# Low utilization of the A100 GPU with fastai

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, gpu, fast-ai

I am currently using fastai to train computer vision models.

I use a development environment of this style.

**On this machine we have :**

```
CPU 16 cores 
RAM 64go 
GPU Nvidia A100
SSD 200go
```

I devellope on a jupyterlab container, on a 1 node docker swarm cluster.
The jupyterlab instance is installed on this image :
nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:23.01-py3

When I launch a training the GPU is not used at 100% it is more or less at 20% and the GPU memory is well exploded according to my batch_size.
Here is a screenshot :

[GPU Utilization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/js7kO.png)

I run a training via pytorch with the same model, the same data and similar hyperparameters and with pytorch it uses 100% of the GPU power.

I tried to install different versions of pytorch, fastai, cuda but nothing works with fastai the use of my GPU is always limited to 20%.

Would you have a reflection track, to help me to find a solution please?

I tried to install different versions of pytorch, fastai, cuda but nothing works with fastai the use of my GPU is always limited to 20%.

Comment: Its not limited to 20%, and you did not say exactly what you are training, simply put, you are not putting too much computation into the GPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your feedback,

After more hours of investigation I found out what was slowing down my GPU because of this callback ActivationStats

here is the code of my learner:

```
learn = vision_learner(
    dls, 
    'resnet18', 
    metrics=[accuracy, error_rate],
    cbs=[
        CSVLogger(fname='PTO_ETIQUETTE.csv'),
        EarlyStoppingCallback(monitor='valid_loss', min_delta=0.3, patience=10),
        ActivationStats(with_hist=True)
    ],
    pretrained=True
)
```

I don't understand why this callback slows down so much the GPU performance ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `cpu=False` to `ActivationStats(with_hist=True, cpu=False)` would fix it I believe.

It looks like by default, stats computation takes place in cpu as shown [here](https://docs.fast.ai/callback.hook.html#activation-graphs).

```py
 ActivationStats (with_hist=False, modules=None, every=None,
                  remove_end=True, is_forward=True, detach=True, cpu=True,
                  include_paramless=False, hook=None)
```